# Xamarin.Droid cannot convert from uint to Android.content.Res.colorStateList

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use the `SetStroke` method of `GradientDrawable` to Set a Black border to a textView

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.SetStroke(1, 0xFF000000);
```

I can't use it the same way like in java, I'm getting error

```
Error : Argument 2: cannot convert from 'uint' to 'Android.content.Res.colorStateList'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin SetStroke(int width, int color) is not there.

You can use SetStroke(int width, Color color) instead.

Something like this :

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.SetStroke(1, Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.black);
```